# I'm trying to send information from one jframe to another to get data from my database, but it keeps giving null pointer exception, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I'm trying to pass information from a frame using this method;

```
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String regnum = registration.getText();

    editStudent s = new editStudent(regnum);
    s.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

The information is passed but then I want to use the information I got to select data from my database which then returns an error.

```
public editStudent(String regnum) {
    initComponents();

    registration = regnum;
    jLabel4.setText(registration);
}
```

This receives the data.
Then this part is meant to collect the data but doesnt.

```
private void jLabel20MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

try{
String sql = "Select * from students where RegistratioNumber = '"+registration+"'";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
surname.setText(rs.getString("Surname"));
}
}catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}

// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Can I see your stack trace? Print and add you stack trace to the question.

Comment: how do I get that?

Comment: Replace this line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);` with `e.printStackTrace();`. This will print a stack trace in the logger which you can copy

Comment: @EZEKIELSEBASTINE I don’t understand

Comment: copy and paste the entire error message here